# RecyclerView performance if the adapter has more than 2000 objects

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

I have created a list via RecyclerView with more than 2000 items. RecyclerView will recycle controls but the list assigned has more than 2000 objects in it. List might have even 4000 objects as well.

Is it a good idea to have all the objects in the list in memory or there is any other way to manage?

Now if I implement endless scrolling or show loader to load data, it will be added to the list and notifyDataSetChanged(); will be called. But the question remains same to maintain a list of more than 2000 objects.

Suggest better approach for this scenario.

Comment: the bitter approach will be edless scrolling or show lader to load data

Comment: That depends on what kinds of data you have - if it's only text, then no problem.

Comment: @JonasCz - Each object has 4-5 string objects. 4000 objects of this type do not cause any memory issues was only concern.

Answer (score 2):

If u initially have 2000 items then by any mean the RecyclerView will keep them in memory so that it can load them.
But if u r getting these item from network then as u said u can implement infinite scroll, load the item from ur web service as needed and add them to ur list.

Comment: question is not to have more than 2000 objects in memory. Even if the data is fetched from network, objects are added to the same list which eventually increases the size of the list.

Comment: Yes the list size will obviously increase when u will have more item. If u r worried that whether list can have 2000 items then it depend on the memory u have. In normal cases it is not a worry. But as I said I would strongly recommend if data is from web server then get data in pieces bcoz there will be very very few users who will scroll through 2000 items.

Answer (score 0):

i am currently going through same scenario but my data set is way big it has currently 2600 items but i have prepared my list to add nearly 100k items in it, the way i am dealing with this is that:

I am using `.json` file in `res/raw` for my app with the items and loading all items in a List, Ok. Now instead of throwing this List with all items directly to the adapter what i opted to do is to have another List in which i will add items little by little and populate RecyclerView using load more mechanism. And when you have loaded whole items in RV simply clear the previously fetched list to clear memory.

Many people suggest to use `Web Service` or `API` and fetch data repeatedly which is, imo, a bogus approach, because if your app, suppose has 10,00,0000 users and at a time 450,000 user are online and they all doing fetch via load more what will it do to WebServer and above all all requests will eventually fetch data from DB (so many hits to DB.... is always considered as worst approach) so if going this way you also need to take care of API mechanism like implementing middleware data request look up to avoid taking users' request to DB every time and return them data from Web Server layer if the request of user is already made and is cached in this layer (definitely, difficult task but this is how it is being used these days).

If you(or anyone) finds better approach kindly discuss. Hope i helped somehow.

Comment: 1st thing storing json object in raw folder is not possible for all because few people start collecting data as use of app increases. But yes if data is static then we can keep the data raw. And keeping 2 list is a bit overhead only, bcoz u will have the big list in memory first to make the small list and so u will have 2 list in memory. And 2nd thing, talking abt server load a developer who will have so many users will obviously not depend on a normal server machine, he/she will probably have a small cluster.

Comment: 1st thing - yes, but he didn't tell his case.

2nd - keeping two lists will is hectic for memory only when both are persisting and i said Clear the first one when temporary list fills up or another approach while sublisting the parent list and adding it to child list at that time clear that sublist from parent.

3rd Thing, maintaining data over clusters is not an easy task. It requires proper development and organization of those clusters and mainly what devs do they just buy a domain and deploy their DB with Web Server on that domain and that's it...

Answer (score 0):

If the object is too heavy/ or you fetching it from server, then better to manage virtual paging. Let define your page size is 100, in onBind put a check that if it has reached 70%(showing 70th row) of your list then it will make a call to fetch another 100.

And don't worry about RecyclerView/ListView, they have no problem with the list size, because the maximum number of rows created by RecyclerView or ListView is the maximum rows you can view on the page whatever the size of your list is.

Hope it will help.. :)